# Vlookup to search non-unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 excel sheets with below values

Sheet1

```
EmpID AppName AppID [Only AppID is Unique]
```

Sheet2

```
EmpID AppName RequestNum [Only RequestNum is unique]
```

`EmpID` is repeated since there are multiple apps associated with one users
AppName is repeated since there are multiple instances of single app associated to one users

Now, I want to get RequestNum from `Sheet2 into Sheet1`, but it obviously returns me the 1st value in case of duplicates. Concatnating `EmpID & AppName` does not work since it does not make a unique combination. How do I achieve that? Would it be possible with combination of formulae or do I need a macro?

Pasting the sample for my sheets below:

**Sheet1:**

```
EmpID   AppName AppID
A123    App1    UniqueID001
A123    App2    UniqueID002
B444    App66   UniqueID003
B898    App1    UniqueID004
H123    App33   UniqueID005
A123    App1    UniqueID006
B444    App33   UniqueID007
L001    App2    UniqueID008
H123    App1    UniqueID009
```

**Sheet2**:

```
EmpID   AppName RequestNum
A123    App1    UniqueReq001
A123    App2    UniqueReq002
B444    App66   UniqueReq003
B898    App1    UniqueReq004
H123    App33   UniqueReq005
A123    App1    UniqueReq006
B444    App33   UniqueReq007
L001    App2    UniqueReq008
H123    App1    UniqueReq009
A123    App1    UniqueReq010
A123    App2    UniqueReq011
B444    App66   UniqueReq012
B898    App1    UniqueReq013
H123    App33   UniqueReq014
A123    App1    UniqueReq015
B444    App33   UniqueReq016
L001    App2    UniqueReq017
H123    App1    UniqueReq018
```

Comment: You say _Concatnating EmpID & AppName ... does not make a unique combination_.  So what _does_ give you a unique connection between the tables?

Comment: I'm afraid none, the unique values in sheet1 (AppID) are different than unique values in sheet2 (RequestNum)

Comment: So for a given _EmpID_ and _AppName_ how do we know which _RequestNum_ to return?

Comment: Ok, so Sheet1 contains abt 3000 records (say for a particular month)

Comment: & sheet2 contains all the data from all the apps (abt 85-90k records), but the 3000 in sheet 1 are included in sheet2

Comment: You are not making any sence.  I suggest you post a short sample data set for both sheets, including the duplications and the expected return result (edit it into your question)

Comment: Main posted edited, thx already :)

Comment: For eg. If you look @ 1st & 6th record in sheet2, both have same EmpID & AppNAme but the RequestNum is different, i want this in sheet1

Comment: Order doesn't matter as long as all are covered only from sheet1

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample. Do you mean you want all matching ReqID's?  Eg for A123 App1 there are 4 ReqID's.  Do want all of them returned? If so, in one cell of multiple cells?  If not, which one do you want?

Comment: Please add to the sample data the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If Sheet1's *AppID* is unique and Sheet2's *RequestNum* is unique I'm not sure how you would determine which *EmpID* & *AppName* to send Sheet2's *RequestNum* to but here is one possible solution.

[image: RequestNum to AppID]

The formula in D2 is `=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$9,SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$8)+(($F$2:$F$9<>$A2)+($G$2:$G$9<>$B2))*1E+99,,),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2))),"")`. Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Until the OP clarifies what he wants, what is the point of posting this?  As it is you are only guessing

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had this figured out, without any macro or complex formula...

- First i had to sort both the sheets in Emp ID & then on App Name
- Insert new column @ the begining & concatenate Emp ID + App Name
- Inserted 2 new columns after app name: say Count & Unique
- Under count i simply counted the repetations made in 1st Concatenated column using countif
- Under Unique in incremented the value for unique repeatations using if (=IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1)) --> This gives me unique (well..almost unique) values in both the sheet to vlookup on to

Thx for all the help :)

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly on sheet1 you want to display all "RequestNum" from Sheet2 that match "EmpID" and "AppName" on sheet one. There are going to be multiple "RequestNum"s, so I have concatenated the IDs into a string. Also note that multiple rows on Sheet1 will show the same "RequestNum_s", where "AppID" is defferent, but "EmpID" and "AppName" are the same.

formula for D2 on Sheet1:
`=join("; ",filter(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$19,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$19=A2,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$19=B2))`

copy down.

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter but are you mashing together VBA and native worksheet functions here? The directions and cell range references seem to be directed solely at worksheet functionality but `Join` and `Filter` are VBA.

Comment: Doh!! I confused this with another question that was on google sheets!! The filter and join formulas are google-sheets specific, and don't exist in Excell (not natively anyway)